# How would you write $A\setminus(B\setminus C)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know that $(A \setminus B) = \{x: x \in A$ and $x \not \in B)\}$, but am not sure how to write $A\setminus(B\setminus C)$ in the same form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider that $~x\notin B~$ is $~\neg(x\in B)~$.

So you can write: $~A\setminus B= \{x: x\in A\wedge \neg (x\in B)\}~$.

Likewise you can write: $~A\setminus (B\setminus C) = \{x: x\in A \wedge \neg(x\in B\wedge \neg (x\in C)) \}~$.

So, with a little dual negations: $$A\setminus (B\setminus C) = \{x: x\in A \wedge (x\notin B\vee x\in C) \}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align*}
A \setminus (B \setminus C)
&= \{x\mid x \in A \land x \not\in (B \setminus C)\} \\
&= \{x\mid x \in A \land （x \in C \lor x \not\in B)\}
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 0):

$A\setminus(B\setminus C)=\{x:x\in A\wedge(x\not\in B\vee x\in C)\}$

Answer (score 0):

$A - (B - C)$ is the set of all elements in $A$ which are not in $B - C$. $B - C$ is the set of all elements in $B$ that are not in $C$. Thus $A$ consists of all $x$ such that $x \in A$, and $\neg (x \in B\ \text{and}\ x \not \in C)$. You can make this nicer using Boole's identities. I leave this for you to finish (I assume this is a homework problem, so its good practice to complete it yourself).

Answer (score 0):

Let $D = (B \setminus C)$. Then 
$$A \setminus (B \setminus C) = A \setminus D = \{x : x \in A \text{ and } x \not \in D \}$$

Additionally, we have

$$D = (B \setminus C) = \{y : y \in B \text{ and } y \not \in C \}$$

Substituting for $D$, we get

$$A \setminus (B \setminus C) = \{x : x \in A \text{ and } x \not \in \{y : y \in B \text{ and } y \not \in C \} \} $$

Applying definitions of element, etc. we get

$$A \setminus (B \setminus C) = \{x : x \in A \text{ and } (x \not \in B \text{ or } x \in C) \} \} $$